# Lossless compressing TIF file

Tags: image-compression, tiff

I have TIF files that I would like to compress without
losing any data, do you know the best tool for that?
The data is very important. 
The data file looks like this:
I have thousands of them. (It's X-ray data and it's black and white. )
[image]

Comment: You have thousands of black images? What is the native format of the files? What are their file sizes? What operating system and software do you have available to recompress the files?

Comment: @xiota Actually, this is black and white if you change the level of brightness you'd see some white parts. The file type is a TIF and can be read by specific tools.

Comment: If the file is already tif, what's the problem?

Comment: Re, "...X-ray data..." Are the originals [DICOM images?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DICOM) That's a topic that I don't know much about, but if I had DICOM images, I would start by looking for DICOM specific tools. One thing to watch out for: Many "photographic" image formats are limited to eight bits per pixel of intensity. DICOMs might have twelve or fourteen or more bits. If you use the wrong tool, you could end up throwing away a lot of image detail _before_ the "lossless" image compression is applied.

Comment: @SolomonSlow "DICOMs might have twelve or fourteen or more bits" – Do you know whether they have the capability, or are you speculating?

Comment: @xiota, I'm a software developer. I once worked on a software product that displayed MRI images. I didn't come into direct contact with the code that imported DICOM files, but I do remember the concept of _window_ (a.k.a., window _width_) and "level" (a.k.a., window _center_). Those are knobs that the radiologist turns while trying to find important details in the picture. They change the mapping from the full bit-depth of the recorded image to the 8-bits per pixel of the display screen.

Comment: Are they grayscale (more than two levels per image, no color) or binary (just two levels per image) ?  People often say "black and white" when they should say "grayscale".

Comment: @StephenG The original file is in here: https://www.mediafire.com/view/dkec9o4d6j0j367/S0_000.tif/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example image in **png** format seems to only have two states. The **png** is already losslessly compressed, albeit in full color mode, at 16.5 Kbytes.

Thresholding the image to pure Black and White and using **GIF** indexed color mode produces a 10.3 Kbyte file, roughly 2/3 size.

[image: GIF indexed threshold]

---------Edit to try to answer OP's additional questions

Loading the linked original image into GIMP, the image appears to be completely **BLACK**.

[image: Gimp_1]

Note that it is 8-bit Integer Indexed Color.

Now opening up the Histogram function in Gimp.

[image: Histogram]

and exporting a CSV file of the Histogram, we see:

Range start,Value

```
0,1002001.0
1,40674.0
2,0.0
3,0.0
4,0.0
5,0.0
...
255,0.0
```

So the image has a million zeros, 40 thousand one's, and nothing else.

Last but not least is the EXIF data from Gimp / Image / Metadata / View Metadata

[image: Metadata]

You can see the LZW compression here.

I actually extracted the LZW information using a different tool that examined the file format, but this is easier if EXIF is available.

Comment: The original file is uploaded here: https://www.mediafire.com/view/dkec9o4d6j0j367/S0_000.tif/file Please take a look

Comment: @Arash - I looked at the original you linked above. Interestingly it is already 8-bit indexed mode and lossly compressed to 12 KB. Initially the image appears all black but it actually has a single bit threshold. Applying a threshold for **Black** and **White** against the original produces exactly the same image I posted above, and it saves as the same 10.3 KB GIF. *Incidentally I used GIMP to process the image*.

Comment: So you think It already compressed lossy?

Comment: @Arash - Sorry, I typo'd. That should have said **losslessly**. Not lossy!

Comment: Thank you for the information, if we don't consider file size, how can we say it's compressed? Is there any information in the file that, by seeing them, we can conclude that the file is compressed? I'm just curious about that.

Comment: Compressed means a smaller file size, but yes generally, and specifically in this case, the file structure states that it is compressed using LZW.

Comment: you are so nice one last question is there any way to see this by myself?  can GIMP app do this?

Comment: @Arash - I updated my answer with pictures for you.

Answer (score 3):

Programs normally offer LZW compression for TIFF image files, which is 100% lossless.  You should first make sure that your program that opens and views them can handle opening LZW compression (try one first), but LZW is very common for images.

Document files (text page archives, and fax) typically use TIFF with one of the CCITT compressions, also lossless, but which is not normally found in image programs, so that is not a good choice for your images.

Comment: Is TIF the same with TIFF? and how can I see/calculate the compression ratio?

Comment: Yes, same meaning, more or less. The technical specification describing the file format is named TIFF, but the computer file name extension is .TIF ... Compression is variable depending on how compressible the content. The uncompressed data size is 3 bytes per pixel for 24-bit RGB color images, 1 byte per pixel for grayscale, and one bit per pixel for line art files. Plus a small overhead for data tags and for any Exif added. Then it is smaller when written to a compressed file (LZW is perhaps 25% to 50% less). The ratio is the ratio of those two sizes, compressed and uncompressed file sizes.

Comment: BTW, your PNG image is also always losslessly compressed (wtihout any losses), and a bit smaller than TIFF LZW  (but large PNG files are slightly slower to open than TIF LZW), if your reading program is OK opening PNG.  But JPG is relatively heavily compressed, and lossy,  with losses..

Comment: Your PNG image is RGB color mode (3 bytes per pixel before compression), which seems a waste storage-wise, at least less appropriate.  Color mode can also develop false color tints.   It seems to have only two colors, black and one light gray tone.  IMO, grayscale (1 byte per pixel) would make more sense for this one shown and would be 1/3 the file size.